# Django Url Redirect: Why 302 when it should be 200/404?

Tags: python, django, url, django-urls, http-status-code-302

I am trying to find the dead URLS on a website I'm testing, but I am having some issues. I'm testing them by getting the reverse of the namespace:name with the appropriate args input and sending that to the code below. It is possible, but I do not think the issue lies in the reverse of the links as they match the url of the localhost. I thought the code below would work as it returns the links' status code as a 302 redirect.

```
def __init__(self, links):
    self.client = Client()
    self.links = links

def test_responses(self):
    for l in self.links:  # Where links are all the formatted links
        response = self.client.get(l)
        print response.status_code, l
```

However, the more I pry the more it seams that this is not the case. If I pass the arguments directly into the links that are correct, as tested in my localhost server test site then it still prints a 302, however on the site it is a 200

```
302 /contacts/organizations/show/123/  # Terminal output
[10/Feb/2016 10:23:10] "GET /contacts/people/show/123/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5039  # apache localhost output
```

Conversely, if I lead a page to a 404 on the localhost, it still shows up as a 302 in the code's output.

```
302 /contacts/organizations/show/10000/
[10/Feb/2016 10:25:32] "GET /contacts/people/show/10000/ HTTP/1.1" 404 846
```

Why is it not printing out the expected code? and what tips/tricks/ideas could I implement that would fix this issue?

Comment: They are not even the same url, how can you expect the response to be the same?

Comment: @Shang `302 /contacts/people/show/123/`

Comment: For terminal you have `/contacts/organizations/show/123/`, but for apache you have `/contacts/people/show/123/`.

Comment: `[10/Feb/2016 10:57:45] "GET /contacts/organizations/show/123/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4948`  That was my mistake but the idea still applies.

Comment: You need to show us the view function, there's no way we can guess what's going on without checking the code.

Comment: What is the `Location` header on the 302? Where is it redirecting you?

Comment: Any specific part or the whole views.py?

Comment: @PopcornArsonist That was it. There was a mistake in my `Location` in my links.

Comment: @ShangWang and PopcornArsonist thank you both for helping